# postgresql display only the query that take more than 2 minute

Tags: postgresql

I used postgres 9.3

I want to display only the query that take more than 2 minute in running

I added in **postgresql.conf** These lines :

```
log_min_duration_statement = 120000 
log_statement = 'all'
```

but when I check the log file in postgres I found that all query are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
log_statement = none
log_min_duration_statement = 120000
```

[Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html)